# Displaying data from the Object returned by JSON Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I am trying to get data from a server and I am using the JSONP callback due to the cross domain request.  I am able to display only some of the data from the server.  The "Stats" information in the file I can display by using

```
  function(rtac) {
    for(i in rtac) {
      rtacs = rtac[i];
      $("#rtac-list").append(rtacs.Stats.ItemCount + "<hr />");
   }
```

But the part named "Data" I am having issues with.  I have tried ...

```
$("#rtac-list").append(rtacs.Data.Number + "<hr />");
```

... and it does not work.

Here is what the server file returns:

```
{
    "rtac_edin_0749542489": {
        "Data": {
            "1": {
                "Number": "1",
                "Location": "Non fiction (Sighthill)",
                "Status": "Available",
                "LoanType": "Standard loan",
                "DueDate": "",
                "Shelfmark": "",
                "CopyNo": "A19958",
                "ClassNo": "912.4144"
            }
        },
        "Stats": {
            "DueDateCount": 0,
            "ItemCount": 1
        }
    },
    "rtac_edin_0715810782": {
        "Data": {
            "1": {
                "Number": "1",
                "Location": "Non fiction (Sighthill)",
                "Status": "Available",
                "LoanType": "Standard loan",
                "DueDate": "",
                "Shelfmark": "",
                "CopyNo": "A12675",
                "ClassNo": "941.143"
            },
            "2": {
                "Number": "2",
                "Location": "Non fiction (Sighthill)",
                "Status": "On Loan",
                "LoanType": "Standard loan",
                "DueDate": "31 March 2015",
                "Shelfmark": "",
                "CopyNo": "A12675",
                "ClassNo": "941.143"
            },
            "3": {
                "Number": "3",
                "Location": "Non fiction (Sighthill)",
                "Status": "Available",
                "LoanType": "Standard loan",
                "DueDate": "",
                "Shelfmark": "",
                "CopyNo": "A12675",
                "ClassNo": "941.143"
            }
        },
        "Stats": {
            "DueDateCount": 1,
            "ItemCount": 2
        }
    },
    "rtac_edin_0862671906": {
        "Data": {
            "1": {
                "Number": "1",
                "Location": "Non Fiction (Granton)",
                "Status": "Available",
                "LoanType": "Standard loan",
                "DueDate": "",
                "Shelfmark": "",
                "CopyNo": "0017564",
                "ClassNo": "914.1443"
            }
        },
        "Stats": {
            "DueDateCount": 0,
            "ItemCount": 1
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my code for testing purposes:

```
    <html><head><title>RTAC</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"       src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head><body>
    <div id='rtac-list'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var url =  "http://www.lh2cc.net/cwolf/php/dsetask/index.php";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(rtac) {
        for(i in rtac) {
            rtacs = rtac[i];
            $("#rtac-list").append(rtacs.Stats.ItemCount + "<hr />");

        }
    });
   });
    </script>
    </body></html>
```

It seems that the structure of the "Data"  item in the file is giving the issue as it has 3 items and I am unsure how to handle this.

Please assist thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `"1"` part of the object:

```
$("#rtac-list").append(rtacs.Data["1"].Number + "<hr />");
```

To access all of the `Data` structure:

```
for (j in rtac.Data) {
    if (rtac.Data.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
        $("#rtac-list").append(rtac.Data[j].Number + "<hr />");
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
<html><head><title>RTAC</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"       src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head><body>
    <div id='rtac-list'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var url =  "http://www.lh2cc.net/cwolf/php/dsetask/index.php";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(rtac) {
        for(i in rtac) {
            rtacs = rtac[i];
            for (j in rtacs.Data) {
                if (rtacs.Data.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                    $("#rtac-list").append(rtacs.Data[j].Number + "<hr />");
                }
            }
        }
    });
   });
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you this works.  Could you show me how I could add this to my current code so it will work?